# Getting Log4j2 errors

Tags: java, logging, log4j, lombok

My log4j2 properties file:

```
status = warn
name= properties_configuration

#Directory path where log files will be stored
property.basePath = ./log/

#File logger
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d

#Root logger configuration
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

I'm using Lombok @Log4j2 annotation:

```
@Log4j2
public class BotApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegram = new TelegramBotsApi();
        Bot bot = new Bot();
        try {
            telegram.registerBot(bot);
            log.info("Bot successfully connected.");
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            log.error("Can't start Bot. Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Application writes logs to file correctly, but always when i run my app i got errors in my console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Seems that these errors don't affect to the logger, but I would like to remove them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages that being with "log4j:WARN" are coming from log4j 1.x. This error means you have the log4j 1.x jar in your classpath but do not have a Log4j 1.x configuration present.

If you do not want to use log4j 1 (and you shouldn't) then add the log4j-1.2-api jar from Log4j 2 to your project.